# How to check if two vars have the same reference?

Tags: javascript, equality

How can you check if two or more objects/vars have the same reference?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You use `==` or `===` :

```
var thesame = obj1===obj2;
```

[From the MDN :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal
>   references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in
>   memory.

Comment: This works in most cases, and may work for the original poster. However, if two strings were fabricated independently and contain the same contents, then `==`, `===` and `Object.is` will all return true after performing a deep string comparison. In the strictest sense, the original poster wants the comparison to return false. I ran across an arcane situation where I also wanted that comparison to be false, and could not find a good solution. What I really need is the JS equivalents of Object.referenceEquals from .NET

Comment: and how to display its reference ?

Comment: @getName You mean the *internal* reference ? It's managed by the implementation, is implementation defined, and isn't exported.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I mean the reference of an object or a primitive variable and wants to know this reference, to perform some tests, I know it can be shown in some other languages like python, but not sure it's possible on JS

Comment: idea: since internal reference is managed by implementation and isn't exposed we can do the following trick: we'll try to temporarily add +1 randomly named new property with random value on the 1st object and then check if expected property happen to appear on the 2nd object! Of cause we'd check if that property does not exist before adding and we'd cleanup after our intrusive check.

Comment: @bigh_29 not sure if when you wrote your comment it was like that, but I just tried now in Chrome and `new String("b") === new String("b")` returns `false`.

Answer (score 20):

As from `ES2015`, a new method [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) has been introduced that can be used to compare and evaluate the sameness of two variables / references:

Below are a few examples:

```
Object.is('abc', 'abc');     // true
Object.is(window, window);   // true
Object.is({}, {});           // false

const foo = { p: 1 };
const bar = { p: 1 };
const baz = foo;

Object.is(foo, bar);         // false
Object.is(foo, baz);         // true
```

**Demo:**

```js
console.log(Object.is('abc', 'abc'));
console.log(Object.is(window, window));
console.log(Object.is({}, {}));

const foo = { p: 1 };
const bar = { p: 1 };
const baz = foo;

console.log(Object.is(foo, bar));
console.log(Object.is(foo, baz));
```

***Note:*** This algorithm differs from the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.

Comment: can I edit your answer? I will add some more examples of Object.is() with Object.assign(), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) etc all

Answer (score 18):

The equality and strict equality operators will both tell you if two variables point to the same object.

```
foo == bar
foo === bar
```

Answer (score 13):

For reference type like objects, **==** or **===** operators check its reference only.

e.g

```
let a= { text:'my text', val:'my val'}
let b= { text:'my text', val:'my val'}
```

here a==b will be false as reference of both variables are different though their content are same.

but if I change it to

```
a=b
```

and if i check now a==b then it will be true , since reference of both variable are same now.

Answer (score -1):

Possible algorithm:

```
Object.prototype.equals = function(x)
{
  var p;
  for(p in this) {
      if(typeof(x[p])=='undefined') {return false;}
  }

  for(p in this) {
      if (this[p]) {
          switch(typeof(this[p])) {
              case 'object':
                  if (!this[p].equals(x[p])) { return false; } break;
              case 'function':
                  if (typeof(x[p])=='undefined' ||
                      (p != 'equals' && this[p].toString() != x[p].toString()))
                      return false;
                  break;
              default:
                  if (this[p] != x[p]) { return false; }
          }
      } else {
          if (x[p])
              return false;
      }
  }

  for(p in x) {
      if(typeof(this[p])=='undefined') {return false;}
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about detecting identical references, not equality.