# How to visually compare two big javascript objects with two different console.log calls

Tags: javascript, object

In C++ I can just print address of object and check if addresses are same. How can I do something similar in JavaScript ? I can't compare these two objects as I don't have references to them at the same time so I console.log the which gives me very long human readable object which is hard to compare.

Comment: This question has already been answered here. Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685079/how-to-check-if-two-vars-have-the-same-reference

Comment: @Adam pls put more effort reading my question cause u missed the part where I don't have reference to these objects at the same time

Comment: So a question - when you mean 'identical', does this mean that the order of the key/value pairs has to be the same or not? In other words would {'a':'xxx', 'b':'yyy'} be considered identical to {'b':'yyy','a':'xxx'} i.e. is the order of the key/value pairs to be preserved?

Comment: Can you stringify the two objects then hash them? If they're identical then the hashes will be the same. sha256 has a very low collision rate and you'd only need to compare two 64 character length strings so that could work. There's a hashing function here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t/48161723#48161723

Answer (score 1):

A solution would greatly differ depending on the type of object you compare, or on what you want to compare between the two.

Since you cannot have references to them at the same time (you could still try to no?) you are correct at dumping the object's value in console... I'd suggest you take both string values and run a comparison on the strings. Maybe with something like https://text-compare.com/ or your IDE.