# How to find the index of an array of objects after it is linked to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Consider this code which creates a sequence of links to (not copies from) elements in the `items` array -

```
class Item { constructor(text) { this.text = text; }}
let items = [new Item ('a'), new Item ('b'), new Item ('c'), new Item ('a')]
let sequence = [items[0], items[3], items[1]]
console.log(sequence[2].text); //'b'
```

Let's prove that `sequence` is linked to (not copied from) elements in the `items` array -

```
items[1].text= 'bb'; 
console.log(sequence[2].text); //'bb'
```

From visual inspection of the code, we see that `sequence[1]` is linked to `items[3]`.

```
console.log(sequence[1].text); //'a'
```

How could we programmatically determine which index of `items` that an element of `sequence` is linked to ? For example `sequence[1]` is linked to index `3` of the `items` array.

Comment: Loop over it (or use array functions for that), and compare using strict equality? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality#description: _"If both operands are objects, return true only if they refer to the same object."_

Comment: also [How to check if two vars have the same reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685079/how-to-check-if-two-vars-have-the-same-reference) and [Get the index of the object inside an array, matching a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.findIndex` to find the specific index.

```js
class Item { constructor(text) { this.text = text; }}
let items = [new Item ('a'), new Item ('b'), new Item ('c'), new Item ('a')]
let sequence = [items[0], items[3], items[1]]

let currentItem = sequence[2];
let indexOfItems = items.findIndex(a => a === currentItem);
console.log('sequence[2] is items[' + indexOfItems + ']');
```

Comment: flag as duplicate.

Comment: @pilchard yes but here it uses `findIndex` to get there and it's adding something

Comment: I tire of people with enough rep to know to flag to close not doing so. There are plenty of ['findIndex' duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition) and the condition is covered by the one I flagged. If every question had to be answered with specific syntax and variable naming to match the question this site would lose its meaning. ([The map and the territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Map_and_the_Territory))

Comment: @pilchard I just meant to fix things the formal way...in this latest duplicate you shared, surely the accepted answer does the same as you pointed out before

Answer (score 0):

Using the [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) operator `===` we can check whether two references refer to the same object.

```js
sequence[1] === items[3] // true
sequence[0] === items[0] // true
sequence[0] === items[3] // false
```

So to know which sequence object refers to which items object, just iterate over both and compare them with the strict equality operator.